# PDO gather BLOB files

Tags: pdo, blob

I'm trying to find a way to output whatever BLOB files are inserted into a silly database. In my code when I query the CV column I get all sorts of weird symbols. Can you guys please help me fix my code?

```
    $crud->dataview($query);
        }else{
        $query = "SELECT id, from_unixtime(cheie_wp) as `datetime`, nume, prenume, email, telefon, oras, denumiri_job, cv FROM jobselection_data_old ORDER BY id DESC";
        $records_per_page=10;
        $newquery = $crud->paging($query,$records_per_page);
        $crud->dataview($newquery);

public function dataview($query)
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
        {
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {

                $date_in = $row['datetime'];
                $date_out = explode(' ', $date_in);

                ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $date_out[0]; ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['nume']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['prenume']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['email']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['telefon']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['oras']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['denumiri_job']); ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php 

            if($row['cv'] != NULL) { ?>

                <a href="view.php?id=<?php print ($row['id']) ?>">view</a>

            <?php }else{

                echo '-';

            }

            ?></td>
                <td align="center">
                <a href="edit-data.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['user_id']); ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                <a href="delete.php?delete_id=<?php print($row['user_id']); ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></a>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }else{ ... }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have modified my code and added view.php with this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
     {

         $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT cv FROM jobselection_data_old WHERE id=:id");
         $stmt->execute(array(":id"=>$_GET['id']));
         $stmt->bindColumn(1, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
         $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

        header('content-type: image/jpeg');
        echo $lob;

     }
     ?>
```

The problem is that it does not generate the image file I have uploaded to the database.

You can check it at https://ns.jobselection.ro/db/
user/pass: test

I added a screen capture of my database as well: https://ns.jobselection.ro/db/screen.png . I only added one row for testing purposes!

Comment: Wouldn't be better to show a link to download a file with the content of the CV field instead of showing the content of the BLOB field in the HTML? The browser won't know to handle that and will just show the ASCII or UTF-8, etc symbols that represent every single characters in the BLOB content.

Comment: I have modified my code, but I'm still having problems reading the file

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is really weird. I found what the issue was. I had my require configuration files in a separate php block of code in the same file. Until I placed them both in the same block of code it did not work!

Comment: Good on you! But I still don't get exactly how your code was before and how you fix it. It's indeed weird that you fix the issue by just getting the required code and merging it into the main php script. Please, share the changes if possible. Github, perhaps? ^^